# Javascript regex is not accurate, sometime is true, sometime is false

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex:

```
a=/((09|03|07|08|05)+([0-9]{8})\b)/g
```

And a string here:

```
b="0977466666"
```

Then when I try to use a.test(b), sometime it is true and sometime it is false and I do not know why but if I omit `g` flag, it is always true.